# Facebook Share: Details are not changing dynamically

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4

Even though the og tags are changed in the head tag, the details(title, description and image) is not updated in Share Modal. Please help.

Comment: You can try to see if the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) is able to see the updated og data.

Comment: since the data is changing dynamically based on the user login, The debugger picks up the default data, and the same data is shown on share modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out myself. So when a url is put into og:url, facebook actually scrapes that url(og:url) and not where its actually mentioned. This should be a sufficient hint if you face the same issue.